# Switch between virtual desktops by scrolling on the menu bar

Tags: script, desktop, ui

Looking for a script, macro, automation script, TIY solution that will allow me to hover my mouse over the menu bar scroll my mouse wheel up and down which in turn will switch between my left and right virtual desktops.

Is this possible to do on macOS?

Comment: What kind of mouse do you have?

Comment: Very simple Logitech m100 mouse

Comment: OK. I don't know of anything that would register specifically if you were in the menu area. What's wrong with the standard key commands?

Comment: @Tetsujin See [an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37prmhmzange8lf/dash-to-panel-demo.mp4?dl=0) on Linux using [Dash to Panel](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel) menu bar.

Comment: @Tetsujin just found this feature very useful on Linux and was wondering if there is any way of even registering mouse hover on the menu bar. Must be a very low-level OS feature that would only require Apple to implement.